# Writing python conditionals for crontab

Tags: python, linux, cron

How does a python if statement work when editing it in crontab?  Using python 3.6.3

Using linux crontab I am trying to get a count of the amount of hidden files within a directory (other than the directories "." and "..") so I can schedule an alert. The following gets the amount in string format:

```
import subprocess
res = subprocess.run('ls -Ap | egrep "^\..*/$" | wc -l', shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
print(res.stdout)

output>>> (integer type string)
```

Then I want something like

```
if res.stdout != "0":
   (executeAlert.sh script)
else:
   (ignore)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much better solution is to avoid a subprocess entirely. (And even if you use a subprocess, [don't use `ls` in scripts.)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

```py
from pathlib import Path

dotfiles = Path().glob('.[!.]*')
if len(list(dotfiles)) > 0:
    do_things()
```

Actually, there is no real need to check the length; you can say

```py
dotfiles = list(Path().glob('.[!.]*'))
if dotfiles:
    do_things('The files which matched are %s' % dotfiles)
```

Somewhat obscurely, but more succinctly, you could iterate over the generator instead; the loop body will be executed only if there is at least one file which matches. This is an optimization if you only care whether there is at least one file, as it stops once it finds the first one;

```py
for file in Path().glob('.[!.]*'):
    do_things()
    break
```

Python doesn't care whether you run your script from `cron` or not (though sometimes you need to arrange the environment for Python in your `cron` job if you have libraries installed in nonstandard locations). But why are you using Python at all here if all your business logic is in shell scripts? (Though your shell scripting could also benefit from studying some [antipatterns to avoid.)](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc)

Here's the whole thing entirely in shell script, using similar logic:

```sh
for file in .[!.]*; do
    test -e "$file" || break  # cf nullgbob
    executeAlert.sh
    break
done
```

Bash offers `shopt -s nullglob` to avoid entering the loop if the wildcard has no match; but `cron` runs `sh` and it's not altogether hard to avoid bashisms here (though the globbing behavior in the case of no matches *is* surprising).

If you want all the matches in a shell script, you can say

```sh
set -- .[!.]*
if [ "$@" != ".[!.]*" ]; then
    executeAlert.sh "$@"   # argument is list of matching files
fi
```

If you use Bash or ksh, you could collect the matches into an array;

```sh
shopt -s nullglob
dotfiles=(.[!.]*)
for file in "${dotfiles[@]}"; do
   echo "Here's one dotfile: $file"
done
if [[ "${#dotfiles[@]}" > 0 ]]; then
     executeAlert.sh "${dotfiles[@]}"
fi
```

Your `egrep` regex would only match on dot *directories;* I have assumed that this was a mistake.

Comment: The last shell script works and I have the executeAlert.sh triggering for hidden directories. Is there a way of me capturing the name of the hidden file so that I can state it in the executeAlert,sh echo statement that sends the email? Thanks

Comment: The variable `file` in the last Python snippet contains the first file. The `list()` expression in the earlier example contains all the matching files if you prefer to have them all. I updated the answer to spell this out a little bit.

Comment: I am trying to get your bash solution running. When I run the above  set -o nullglob section of code I receive the error **" set: nullglob: invalid option name"**. I read up on nullglob then tried shopt -s dotglob but it just returned the hidden file continuously in an infinite loop. Thanks @tripleee

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right, `shopt` not `set`; but `nullglob` not `dotglob`. Demo: https://ideone.com/L3aMYC

Answer (score 0):

printing `res.stdout` will show you that it has an endline character within it.

```
>>>res.stdout
'0\n'
```

so just strip the '\n' character:

```
res = res.stdout.strip('\n')
if res == "0":
    (executeAlert.sh script)
```

Alternatively, just cast it as an integer:

```
if int(res.stdout) == 0:
    (executeAlert.sh script)
```